# Why does this python program sometimes fail to exit?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, signals

I wrote a test program, which has two processes. The father process gets data from a Queue, and the child puts data into it. There is a signal handler which tells the program to exit. However, it does not exit sometimes when I send the signal SIGTERM to the pid(child process) I printed, and it seems to be having a deadlock.

```
import os
import sys 
import multiprocessing
import time
import signal

bStop = False
def worker(que):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,sighandler)
    print 'worker:',os.getpid()
    for i in range(100000000):
        que.put(i)

    print 'STOP'

def sighandler(num,frame):
    print 'catch signal'
    q.put('STOP')
    sys.exit(0)
q = multiprocessing.Queue(100)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=(q,))
p.start()

for item in iter(q.get,'STOP'):
    print 'get',item
    pass
print 'main stop'
p.join()
```

Comment: Wow... with 100,000,000 you weren't kidding about that range, were you?

Comment: @cwallenpoole I just want it running for a long time ....

Comment: Well, it's been running in the background for 20 minutes and hasn't gotten to 50,000,000 yet

Comment: @cwallenpoole  Did you find the problem I mentioned above ? you should send SIGTERM to the child process rather than waiting itself to exit.

Comment: I think you are blocking in queue.put method and signals in Python do not interrupt operations that is blocked in the native code.  But I don't understand why is the parent process not clearing the queue.

Comment: @MK I executed strace -p pid and found that it blocked in futex() which may be invoked by sem_wait . I think puting 'STOP' in the signal handler cause the problem ,because I read the source code of multiprocessing and it shows sem_wait interrupted by signal and python will execute PyErr_CheckSignals() ( in Python/Modules/semaphore.c) .I just guess that . I want to know the real reason.

Comment: @reneglish what OS are you running this on btw?  I tried running it on my Mac and it pretty much killed it, and I don't have access to a Linux box with python2.6 atm...

Comment: @MK I am running on Ubuntu 11.04 . I have two cores of my CPU . It may be work well sometimes and sometimes not .

Comment: @MK Sometimes It raise a Full Exception which is nonpossible for my put is "block"

Comment: @MK I ran it three times and got failed one time . This is the result of strace -p pid :
`Process 15333 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0x881edf0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running python 3 you should be using xrange instead of range for a loop that large.  Python tends to choke once it exceeds a certain list size and so you really really need to move to generators by that point.

That very well could be the issue your seeing right now.